# Handling HomeKit Security through a WiFi router upgrade

Tags: security, router, homekit

I'm replacing my HK enabled WiFi router with a new one and I understand that as long as the network name and password are the same, I don't need to remove and read any of my HK devices, however I'm not clear how to handle [HK Security](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/securing-routers-with-homekit-seccab60e931/web). Specifically, what steps do I need to take regarding disabling and or enabling HK Security on the old and new routers.

In other words is it (A)

1. Disable HK Security on old router
2. Remove old router
3. Add new router
4. Enable HK Security on new router

or is it (B)

1. Remove old router
2. Add new router
3. Enable HK Security on new router

or is it simply — and somewhat magically — (C)

1. Remove old router
2. Add new router

It seems like (C) wouldn't work and that (B.3) would be an essential step, so the basic question is whether I should (or should *not*) disable HK security on the old router before removing it (A.1).

Comment: I’m curious. What model and version are the old and new routers?

Comment: @bmike The "old" router is a (total crap) Linksys WHW0301 Velop Mesh Router, and the new one is an eero Pro 6 (which I'm hoping will work). Whatever you do, to not go near the Velop: worst technical experience I've ever had (and I've been at this a *long* time).

Comment: Sadly, I have been on the “avoid HomeKit” train for a Ks for the excellent side detail. It shouldn’t matter for the question. I hope eero makes you happy. I know several people that love the velop, but maybe they have newer models

Comment: @bmike HK isn't perfect but it's no worse than a lot of the alternatives I've used up until now. And it's in the kill zone so most of the others will die eventually.